# Apache is not beign started

Tags: postgresql, xampp

I wanted to integrate postgresql in wordpress. To see postgres in xampp control panel I tried to do something. After that I could not be able to start apache. When I try to do that the following message is shown.

2:59:25 PM  [Apache]    Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.

```
2:59:25 PM  [Apache]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
2:59:25 PM  [Apache]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
2:59:25 PM  [Apache]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
2:59:25 PM  [Apache]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
2:59:25 PM  [Apache]    If you need more help, copy and post this
2:59:25 PM  [Apache]    entire log window on the forums
```

Can anyone help me in this purpose

Comment: "I tried to do something" What did you did?

Comment: I changed some instances in the configuration file but forgot what I changed. I checked and found postgres is running on the same port as the apache. So I changed the port of apache. But it isn't working.

Comment: You should change back your apache port to default and change your postgre port to an other one like with `postgres -p 1486`